# calling controller action from javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i have a link that calls into a javascript to give a confirmation:

```
$("a.delete").click(function() {
    var name = $(this).parent().prev('td').prev('td').text();
    jConfirm('Are you sure you want to delete the following member:' + name, 'Member Delete', function(r) {
    });
});
```

i want, if the user clicks yes to call a controller action similar to what this code does:

```
 <%= Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Mail_ID })%>
```

how can i get the functionality of the jquery confirmation popup but still get the same results after that i would with the actionlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
<%= Url.Action("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Mail_ID }) %>
```

to generate just the actual url (without the `<a href="..." >...</a>`). That way you can just render that into your javascript & use `window.location`, so your javascript becomes (assuming that function at the end of your `jConfirm` is the call back on acceptance):

```
$("a.delete").click(function() {
    var name = $(this).parent().prev('td').prev('td').text();
    jConfirm('Are you sure you want to delete the following member:' + name, 'Member Delete', function(r) {
        window.location = <%= Url.Action("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Mail_ID }) %>;
    });
});
```

---

Another alternative, which would mean that it would still work (sans the confirmation) if they didn't have javascript enabled would be to leave the link as it is & then do this:

```
$("a.delete").click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr("href");
    var name = $(this).parent().prev('td').prev('td').text();
    jConfirm('Are you sure you want to delete the following member:' + name, 'Member Delete', function(r) {
        window.location = url;
    });
});
```

which grabs the url directly from the link (i.e. the one generated by your original `<%= Html.ActionLink...`).

Comment: i am getting the following error with this code:

CS0103: The name 'item' does not exist in the current context

Comment: ...well that bit's your code, I just copied it from your question.

Comment: Oh. Unless you're trying to use my first example, but you've got your javascript declared in a different scope to wherever your `item` is. In which case the second version should still work (using your original `Html.ActionLink`).